# Waiting until a window exists in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to work with the script below and the `repeat until exists window "Print"`loop never returns true (I never hear the beep 3). Is this the correct way to wait for a window to appear?

I am using the Accessibility Inspector and this is the correct name of the print dialog window.

```
# Saves current document open in EverNote as PDF
#
activate application "Evernote"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "EverNote"
        # Open the print dialog
        beep 1
        keystroke "p" using command down

        # Wait until the Print dialog opens before proceeding
        repeat until exists window "Print"
        end repeat

        # Expand the "PDF" menu button (must be expanded before the menu is referencable)
        beep 3

        click menu button "PDF" of window "Print"
        # Wait until the Menu button menu is created before proceeding
        repeat until exists menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print"
        end repeat
        # Select the "Save as PDF" menu item
        click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print"

        # Wait until the Save dialog opens before proceeding
        repeat until exists window "Save"
        end repeat

        # Paste the contents of the clipboard in and Save
        # This is sorta hack; Probably best to leave the 'Save As" dialog open and let the user finish it off but I have a special purpose
        if (get (the clipboard) is not "") then
            set value of text field 1 of window "Save" to get (the clipboard) & ".pdf"
        end if
        click button "Save" of window "Save"

    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 12):

I seem to have fixed the main problem of the "waiting for window" issue. Apparently nested "tells" are not so good - so I solved this by specifying the process which owns a particular UI element:

```
repeat until window "Print" of process "Evernote" exists
```

Haven't solved putting the current date into the filename field of the "Save" sheet yet but tomorrow is another day! Here's the full script:

```
activate application "Evernote"
tell application "System Events"

    # Open the print dialog
    keystroke "p" using command down

    # Wait until the Print dialog opens before proceeding
    repeat until window "Print" of process "Evernote" exists
    end repeat

    click menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of process "Evernote"

    # Wait until the Menu button menu is created before proceeding
    repeat until exists menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of process "Evernote"
    end repeat

    # Select the "Save as PDF" menu item
    click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of process "Evernote"

    # Wait until the Save dialog opens before proceeding
    repeat until exists window "Save" of process "Evernote"
    end repeat

    set theDate to current date

    #tell (current date) to get (it's month as integer) & "-" & day & "-" & (it's year as integer)
    #set the clipboard to result as text

    #set myDate to result as text
    #set the clipboard to "dog" as text
    #if (get (the clipboard) is not "") then
    #set value of text field 1 of sheet "Save" of process "Evernote" to get (the clipboard) & ".pdf"
    #end if

    set value of text field of sheet "Save" of process "Evernote" to "dog" & ".pdf"
    # Paste the contents of the clipboard in and Save
    # This is sorta hack; Probably best to leave the 'Save As" dialog open and let the user finish it off but I have a special purpose

    # click button "Save" of window "Save" of process "Evernote"


end tell
```

Comment: I have also used `tell application "System Events" to tell process "MyProcess" ... blah` with some success.

Comment: Does repeat until window "Print" of process "Evernote" exists really work for you? When I try exact that line I get a compilation error pointing at " before Evernote "Expected end of line but found “"”."

Comment: @d-b – was a couple of years ago so I don't really recall – but I think, yeah, it did work.

Comment: @d-b regarding the error, and for those who still need help with this, this answer describes the problem and provides the solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274503/343650