# Search for page number with PDF Expert and Applescript

Tags: applescript, pdf

I'm trying to write an Applescript script that will open a pdf `agile.pdf` with `PDF Expert` and search for a page number.

I'm getting close with the following script:

```
do shell script "open agile.pdf"
delay 1.0

tell application "System Events" 
  tell application process "PDF Expert"
    click menu item "Go to Page..."  of menu 1 of menu bar item "Go"  of menu bar 1
    keystroke "42"
    key code 76
  end tell
end tell
```

The problem is my script as it is will only work if I've already "clicked into" a `PDF Expert` window.

Is it possible for me to tell Applescript to "click into the PDF Expert window after it opens?

Also, it is possible for me to tell Applescript to "wait until the window exists?

I was reading [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121855/180817) that makes it look like the following will work but it doesn't:

```
repeat until window "agile" of process "PDF Expert" exists
end repeat
```

I've done some poking around with UIElementInspector as recommended in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/346984/277471). This is the output of the `PDF Expert` window:

```
<AXApplication: “PDF Expert”>
 <AXWindow: “agile”>
  <AXSplitGroup>
   <AXScrollArea>

Attributes:
   AXHorizontalScrollBar:  “<AXScrollBar>”
   AXParent:  “<AXSplitGroup>”
   AXChildren:  “<array of size 5>”
   AXFocused (W):  “1”
   AXSize:  “w=892 h=649”
   AXRole:  “AXScrollArea”
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “agile”>”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXChildrenInNavigationOrder:  “<array of size 5>”
   AXPosition:  “x=292 y=-803”
   AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “agile”>”
   AXRoleDescription:  “scroll area”
   AXVerticalScrollBar:  “<AXScrollBar>”
   AXContents:  “<array of size 3>”
   AXFrame:  “x=292 y=-803 w=892 h=649”

Actions:
   AXScrollLeftByPage - scroll left by a page
   AXScrollRightByPage - scroll right by a page
   AXScrollUpByPage - scroll up by a page
   AXScrollDownByPage - scroll down by a page
```

Comment: I don't have the app to test with, but `tell application process "PDF Expert" to activate` will make sure it comes to the front, & also will incidentally drop the other commands back to System Events.

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you please provide an example. I don't know where to put your line in my code.

Comment: I need to somehow tell Applescript to "click on the PDF Expert window" otherwise PDF Expert won't respond to the rest of the commands. So far `activate application "PDF Expert"` doesn't work.

Comment: Why using a shell script to open the file; doesn't PDFExpert support the open command? You might check that in the dictionary of PDFExpert. It also should fully support the activate command.

Answer (score 1):

`PDF Exper` and `keystroke "42"` doesn't work for me.

However, using `Skim` and `key code` works:

```
do shell script "open -a Skim agile.pdf"
delay 0.1

tell application "System Events" 
  tell application process "Skim"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Skim" to click menu item "Go to Page…" of menu "Go" of menu bar 1
    delay 0.1
    key code {21, 19, 36}
  end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
do shell script "open agile.pdf"
delay 1.0
activate application "PDF Expert"
delay 1 -- you may need to adjust this
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "PDF Expert"
        click menu item "Go to Page..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "Go" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Doesn't work, for some reason `PDF Expert` doesn't recognize Applescript commands unless it's been "clicked" on. I'm experimenting with `Skim` seems to be working better.

Comment: That is quite odd because I just downloaded PDF expert and ran the script myself and it works..  You might want to try adjusting the delay times.  I ran the script without your "do shell script command"  I had a PDF expert already opened with a document opened.  Then I ran the script.

Comment: So strange...definitely only works for me if I first click into the window and then run the script. I'm also not able to `keystroke "123"`, I have to `key code {18,19,20}`