# Applescript - wait for window/dialog to appear/disappear

Tags: applescript, dialog

I am scripting iTunes and have bumped into two problems when I in one step of my script need to verify wether windows/dialogs are displayed or not.

1. According to [Waiting until a window exists in Applescript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121810/waiting-until-a-window-exists-in-applescript) this should be valid code

   `repeat until window "Print" of process "Evernote" exists`

but when I compile it I get this error message "Expected end of line but found “"” (" refers to the " before E in Evernote). Why? That question is 2,5 years old, has anything changed since then? I am running OS X 10.11.

2. I can use this code to verify wether the song info-window is open in iTunes

   `repeat until (not (exists window "Song Info"))`

but when I try to look for en Open dialog with a similar line

```
repeat until (exists window "Open")
```

the window is not detected. I have used Accessibility Inspector to get some properties of the Song Info window and the Open dialog and the only differences I have noticed is the name as well as the type. Song Info is a "window" while Open is a "dialog". Hence, I also tried these two variations on the previous code:

```
repeat until (exists dialog "Open")
repeat until (exists window dialog "Open")
repeat until (exists dialog window "Open")
```

but none of them compile.

How do I detect the Open dialog?

Comment: I just realised that if I inspect an Open dialog in iTunes its type is "dialog" but if I inspect an Open dialog in Script Editor its type is "window".

Comment: If the example _code_ in my answer doesn't address the "Open dialog" you're referring to, then please edit your question to better reflect exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're getting "**Syntax Error** Expected end of line but found “"”." when using `repeat until window "Print" of process "Evernote" exists` is because you're using it out of context of the calling application. You might say meaning, within the context of the calling application, it doesn't understand the command and the AppleScript Editor is not that well written to express what the error really means.

Anyway, the example *code* below when run in ScriptEditor, by itself, will wait to display the "Your wait is over!" *dialog box* until **iTunes** is open and you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or click **File** > **Add to Library…** on the **iTunes** *menu*.

```
tell current application
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (exists window "Add To Library" of application process "iTunes")
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
    activate
    display dialog "Your wait is over!"
end tell
```

- Note the use of the `delay` *command* within the `repeat` *loop*. Obviously the *value* can be set to something else, even *fractions of a second*, however you should alway use a delay to avoid **System Events** from needlessly triggering the *loop* hundreds of time a second until the *condition* is meet.

As a general rule I've found that anytime I'm using *code* that has `... process ...` or `... application process ...` it's a *call* being made *to* or *by* **System Events** and as such in this use case, the `repeat` *loop* has to be within a `tell` *statement* or *block* of **System Events** in order to not get the *error* mentioned in your OP.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for your general rule. It makes very much sense when it is pointed out like that. Interestingly enough, I needed to add Script Editor System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility when I added the "tell system events" block.

Comment: However, I am not done yet: this »repeat until (exists window "Add To Library" of application process "iTunes")» works fine but when I add a "not" to it: »repeat until (not exists window "Add To Library" of application process "iTunes")» the code fail to compile with a warning and refuses to run with the same warning "Can’t get not (exists window "Song info"). Access not allowed." What access is required for this negative case to work?

Comment: @d-b, Please use proper _code formatting_, a backtick '`', not '»' when expressing _code_ in a comment as it makes it easier to read.

Comment: @d-b, In my example _code_, changing `repeat until (exists window "Add To Library" of application process "iTunes")` **to** `repeat until (not (exists window "Add To Library" of application process "iTunes"))` works for me. That said, anytime you're looking for help debugging _code_ please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to enable us to reproduce the issue as you've encountered it. Otherwise, we have to guess at the context of the issue and that's not conducive to providing quality answers.

Comment: @d-b, BTW In my example _code_, changing the `repeat` _loop_ to `repeat until (not (exists window "Song Info" of application process "iTunes"))` also works of me.

Comment: @d-b, You can also use, e.g.: `repeat while not (exists window "Song Info" of application process "iTunes")`